# Wincache using with php

Tags: php, caching, wincache

I'm using wincache to store the value persistent. I'm using the below code to store the value

```
 $newhighlowarray = array();
    //high low calculation
   if(wincache_ucache_exists("Highlow")) {
        $existhighlowarray = wincache_ucache_get("Highlow");
        $isexist = true;

       $newhighlowarray = /* Calculations*/;
    }

    wincache_ucache_set("Highlow", $newhighlowarray);
```

I need to store value without time expire, i will update the cache for every second because of value changes in my stock market.

But this cache get clear some of the time and also some time happening 500 internal server error this time also getting clear the cache.How to store the value persistent with out clear my cache. Please help anyone.

My hosting server windows server with iis7

Answer (score 1):

By default, the wincache_ucache_set function uses a ttl=0, which means the entry should never be expired.

To get some insight, you should check in the php_errors log when you get the 500 internal server error.  There should be some information on why the request failed.